# Mark the checkbox true in html email template on basis of checked in form

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have to send an email which contains some checkboxes.My aspx form also have same checkboxes which is in html email template but form checkboxes are asp controls.

If user ticks on 1 checkbox and other checkbox is unselected,
then how can i send the check value to html template and get into html template and select,unchecked the
checkboxes in html template according to selected by user in form.

html checkboxes and aspx form checkboxes both have same text.

Comment: show your code so we can better understand your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you generating and formatting the email? Are you doing it in VB.NET/C# with System.Net.Mail? If you are doing it the way I think you may be, I think your best bet would be to pass an array of true/false values when you format the body of the email using the template, and check/uncheck the checkboxes in the email using these values. For example:

```
//Determine which checkboxes are checked and add them to the array.
Dim checkedBoxes New ArrayList
checkedBoxes.Add(IIf(chk_first.Checked, "checked", ""))
checkedBoxes.Add(IIf(chk_second.Checked, "checked", ""))
checkedBoxes.Add(IIf(chk_third.Checked, "checked", ""))

//Then you'd have your email generation code here. This is only the body part of it.
email.Body = String.Format(File.ReadAllText([YourTemplateFile]), checkedBoxes.ToArray())
```

Of course I'm making a lot of assumptions here. Then, in your template file, each checked value would use a true/false value from the array, so the first one would have:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="check1" {0} />
```

I hope this helps. If I am way off, post the code you are using to generate and send the email and I'll be able to help more.

Comment: So it didn't work for you? Did it give you any errors? Please post the code you are using, otherwise it's a guessing game to figure it out. Or are you having a problem because I posted a VB.NET example when you require C#?

Comment: On line
string body = string.Format(File.ReadAllText(@"D:\emailer.txt"),chkboxes);
it gives the following exception
Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: I tried also this
string body = GetEmailMessageBody(File.ReadAllText(@"D:\emailer.txt"), chk1.Checked, chk2.Checked, chk3.Checked, chk4.Checked);
   <br/>         
 public static string GetEmailMessageBody(string ResourceContent, params object[] Values) {
            try
            {
                return string.Format(ResourceContent, Values);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
<br/>
But this code ticks all the checkboxes in email,I also have some textboxes in my form,which values is also sent with the checkboxes.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken in my code. Try using an ArrayList instead. See the edited example above.

Comment: Converting ArrayList into array is just same as I was trying, I was collecting all the controls in object type array, Again problem is same, I checked only 2 checkboxes, but When i received the email,it had all checkboxes marked as true.

Comment: I did some more testing and the same thing was happening to me too. I found that if the checked attribute was present at all, no matter its value, it would display checked. So you have to have the attribute or leave it out for this to work correctly, like so:

`<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="check1" {0} />`

This will be checked:

`<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="check1" checked />`

This will not:

`<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="check1" />`

I've updated my answer again with a way for you to load this into the ArrayList.

Comment: Great! Happy to help. If everything's working okay now, please mark the answer as Accepted, so others know that it was the correct solution for your problem. Thanks! :)